# ActiveAdmin/Devise: Create a has_many relationship and form for User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I set up ActiveAdmin and Devise following [this tutorial](http://jaysonlane.net/tech-blog/2012/04/rails-devise-and-active-admin-single-user-model/).

I then created another class and a has_many relationship to my user class:

```
class Household < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :household
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :household
end
```

Then I created a new migration:

```
class AddHouseholdIdToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :household_id, :integer
  end
end
```

The relationship works fine. I can do:

```
@user = User.find(1)
@user.household_id = 1
@user.save
```

and it works. My app/admin/household.rb file seems to be ok (it looks like this:)

```
ActiveAdmin.register Household do

permit_params :name, :users

index do
  column :name
  column :users do |h|
    table_for h.users.order('email ASC') do
      column do |u|
        u.email
      end
    end
  end
  default_actions
end

show do
  attributes_table do
    row :name
    table_for household.users.order('email ASC') do |t|
      t.column("Email") { |user| user.email }
    end
  end
end

form do |f|
  f.inputs "Add/Edit Household" do
    f.input :name
    f.input :users, :as => :check_boxes, :label => "Email"
  end
  f.actions
end

end
```

And I can view, edit, etc.

My problem is, that the same does not work for my app/admin/user.rb file. It currently looks like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do

    permit_params :email, :household

  index do
    column :email
    column :household

    default_actions
  end

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "User Details" do
      f.input :email     
      f.input :household
    end
    f.actions
  end

  show do
    attributes_table :email, :household
  end
end
```

Index and Show are working fine, but when I try to edit or create a new user via the ActiveAdmin interface, I get the following error:

```
  Rendered ./.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/active_admin-fdc6a3d9faee/app/views/active_admin/resource/edit.html.arb (70.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 78ms

ActionView::Template::Error (Unable to find input class for ):
    1: insert_tag renderer_for(:edit)
  app/admin/user.rb:21:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
  app/admin/user.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

If I leave app/admin/user.rb empy, I get:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 135ms

ActionView::Template::Error (Unable to find input class for ):
    1: insert_tag renderer_for(:edit)
  ./.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/active_admin-fdc6a3d9faee/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:132:in `rescue in input_class'
  ./.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/active_admin-fdc6a3d9faee/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:121:in `input_class'
[...]
```

I searched the web for a solution, but could not find anything. I'm completely stuck. Does anybody have any idea what the problem might be?

// Edit: If I do the same thing, but use a different class than user, I do not get the error. I can edit and create that class, and I can see the relationships in the form. But the relationships are not saved when saving the form.

// Edit2: In case of non-user classes: it works if I not only allow the class as parameter, but also class_id. so in my example, it would be:

```
permit_params :email, :household, :household_id
```

But this only works for non-user classes, so my problem still exists :(

Comment: try do remove just `f.input :household` and update if you can load the page. and did you run `rake db:migrate`

Comment: @matanco if I remove that line, I get the same error as before

Comment: @matanco oh, and yes, I did run migrate and I restarted the server, but it did not help.